# While testing unloaded half-bridge, driver self-destructs

Tags: mosfet-driver, driver, half-bridge

I have an [IRS2153D](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRS2153D-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46269e1c019016a4ea5480f0d88) configured so that the driver power supply is separate but not isolated from the half-bridge power supply. As soon as I place 12 V across the unloaded half-bridge, the driver bricks itself. Why is this happening? Does it require a load to work properly?

Notes:
The voltages being used here are for testing purposes. RVCC was chosen such that the driver is given a maximum current of 16mA which is within spec of the datasheet(5-20mA). Poking the gates of the MOSFETs with an oscilloscope shows there is more than enough dead time to prevent shoot-through, around 750ns or so. MOSFETs are [IRFP250N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFP250N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356288b8b1fde) with 2.7Ω gate resistors.

This should be the end of the half-bridge saga. Thanks for your help!
[image: half-bridge driver]

Comment: What FETs are you using?

Comment: IRFP250N, 2160pF input capacitance, with 2.7Ω gate resistor

Comment: Destructs or just locks out?

Comment: I checked if it went into UVLO mode by removing all power, discharging all capacitors and repowering it. The driver dies every time.

Comment: What's the value of your bootstrap cap, CBOOT? Can you show your layout? Do you have a solid ground between the 24 V and 12 V supplies? Are the gate voltages ringing more than -0.3 V below ground?

Comment: No ringing, has a solid ground, and am using a 100nF bootstrap cap.

Comment: 100nF seems too small, go for 1 or 10 uF.

Comment: Are you aware you may need to precharge your bootstrap? Or periodically recharge it by activating the lower MOSFET?

Comment: Why 12V? It seems marginal, all internals run on 12V, and the bootstrap needs to be higher. Did you try 24V straight?

Comment: I only apply the 12 V after the oscillation starts, seen on the scope. I have lots of 12 V 7 Ah SLA batteries because they make good grab n' go power supplies. That's why I used 12 V. Two in series for the driver input as one cannot max out the internal zener clamp of 14.5 V. One across the half-bridge just to verify that everything works, but that's where the problem lies. Regarding the bootstrap cap, the IRS2153 has an internal bootstrap drive that charges the cap when the low side is on, so I wouldn't expect that to be the problem.

Comment: Please show photographs of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that when it switches on, big spike goes through Miller capacitance to the driver. 12V doesn't seem enough to kill, maybe it's current. 24V is almost a guaranteed kill, if only it gets to the gate.

Another thing that worries is the 1.5k resistor. It's possible that voltage on VCC drops very low and you get special effects of current flowing back.

Answer (score 0):

Lower the value of RVCC. You're starving the chip. The chip alone needs 5mA of current not including switching/bootstrap current; you have 600uA left in your power budget. RVCC should be dissipating around 1W. Source: page 9 of the datasheet. Also, make sure your MOSFETs aren't already shorted.

Comment: 24/1500 is 16mA. That’s very close to it’s maximum input current of 20mA. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ElectronicsNoob Yes, you are. The calculation is (24V - 15.6V)/1k5 = 5.6mA. Your calculation is assuming the chip drops no voltage.